# Fancy chapter headings

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm searching for nice predefined chapter headings. I've found the `fncychap` package, and seen that `memoir` has quite a few, too.

Do you know other packages that provide predefined fancy chapter styles?

Comment: **titlesec** has some good examples

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if people here published their code for fancy chapters and sections?

Comment: Although this is not included as a standalone package, [Vincent Zoonekynd's LaTeX website](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/) has some nice examples of [section](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html) and [chapter headings](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html), complete with the code that generates them.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Although the `memoir` class, `fancychap`, `titlesec` and others have some predefined chapter styles, I understand your search for something better.

There are two issues to consider here:

1. The limitations of the original LaTeX structure and commands and,
2. The typographical requirements for such an endeavour.

One of the difficulties in the redefinition of chapters, is the different mechanisms provided by the various packages as well as by `LaTeX`. To complicate matters further the code in the `book.cls` is spread in at least four chunks.

An approach to overcome the limitations and provide some more general and well abstracted routines to define a key-value approach similar to those provided by `PGF` keys. I have done some work in this respect sometimes back and a typical setting would be:

```
\cxset{
 name=\so{CHAPTER},
 numbering=arabic,
 number font-size=\large,
 number before={},
 number position=rightname,
 chapter color={black!80},
 chapter font-size=\large,
 chapter before=\rule[3pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par\hfill,
 number after=,
 chapter after=\hfill\hfill\par\rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par,
 number color=\color{black!80},
 title font-family=\bfseries,
 title font-color=\color{black!80},
 title font-weight=,
 title font-size=\LARGE,
 title beforeskip=\hfill\par\hspace*{0pt},
 header style=empty
}
```

Although the keys and the code might at first glance seem overwhelming it can be greatly simplified by the use of `styles`. So once a set of keys has been defined it can be stored in a `.style` command. Another advantage of this method is that community settings can easily be incorporated by the use of libraries. This is important for `TikZ` based designs, where the shapes and complexity cannot be abstracted easily if at all.

This brings us to the second part of the issues associated with chapter re-definitions: typography. The chapter look and feel must blend with the rest of the design. Consider for example the following two images:

[image][image]

It is no good only having definitions for chapters. The style should extend to exercises, tables, sections table of contents and the like. A similar method to using a key-value approach might make this task easier and share the styling among the community. Originally I experimented with `.ini` files and `LuaLaTeX` for loading them. However, the key value approach is better and more familiar to the community.

I have collected over 50 styles from different books and I have the basic code ready for experimentation (only for chapters).

And now the coding part. First we define keys for all major elements:

```
\def\cxset{\pgfqkeys{/chapter}}
\cxset{%
  name/.code={\gdef\chaptername{#1}},
  chapter font-family/.store in=\chapterfontfamily@cx,
  ...
}
```

As we want to use the basic LaTeX structure and conventions, we redefine the
`\@makechapterhead` to handle the keys. Remember that there are two commands used by `LaTeX` to typeset chapter heads. The one is used for the unstarred version of the command, while the other one is for the starred version. The starred version of the command in our approach is unnecessary as we can define a key instruct the typesetting engine to ignore the numbering (`numbering=none`) and hence we redirect both the starred as well as the unstarred version to the same macro.

```
 \renewcommand\@makechapterhead[2][]{%
   ...
   \titlebeforeskip@cx%
   \if@lefttitle%
     \beforenumber@cx%
     \counterdisplay\c@chapter\afternumber@cx%
   \fi
   ...
  }
```

The macro contains the typesetting algorithm and hooks into the various keys. To typeset a chapter head the simplest approach is to define a set of keys as styles. For example we can use:

```
   \cxset{manet/.style={
   name={},
   numbering=none,
   ...
   }
```

to define the style "manet". The chapter is then typeset as:

```
  \cxset{manet}
  \chapter{EDOUARD MANET}
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \leftskip0pt
    \lettrine{I}{psum dolor} sit amet latixeus. \lipsum*[1-2]
    Latinicus porcupinus to fill the line.
  \end{multicols}
```

Giving us the following result:

[image][image]

With slight variations, we can inherit the style and get the "cardinal on a vespa chapter":

```
   \cxset{manet}
   \topimage{<image file>}
   \chapter{ALAN MacDONALD}
```

Additional keys can be defined if necessary to cater for all fields.

Chapters made out of only textual components are easier to define. You just set the style number.

```
   \cxset{style7}
   \chapter{Introduction to Style Seven}
   ...
   \cxset{style12}
   \chapter{Introduction to Style Twelve}
   ...
```

[image][image]

Special chapter openings need a different treatment and are best described as environments, as they tend to have many textual components as well as images:

```
  \begin{specialchapter}[
     image=genetics-dogs,%chromosomes
     image caption={Labrador retriever\\
      ...
     by two gene pairs.}]%
    {Extensions\\ of Mendelian\\ Genetics}
    \begin{itemize}
     ...
    \end{itemize}
  \end{specialchapter}
```

[image][image]

The second image above had only the image key changed, just to illustrate the technique. As a point of interest the images were placed with traditional boxing techniques rather than using `tikZ` or `picture commands`. The shading was achieved by stretching a "shadow" image file, pretty much like it was used on the web in the pre-html5 days.

The technique has proved useful, easy to define and although the documentation still needs to be developed and the code needs a good clean-up and a few must-do; in the meantime you can download the [image samples](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B75n0wtctw00TkRWV2lwVUhUOWFlYl9hVjB6V1JmQQ) (used in the documentation), the [chapterx](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B75n0wtctw00YVJGRmJ4d2FUajZyVFBPTTVPNGU0Zw) package file, the [documentation](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B75n0wtctw00U2pkUUl4UmRUbENuR3E5eWU3R0dDUQ) tex file and the [documentation pdf file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B75n0wtctw00bmRKNllDQzNRMkdEWVdCWW1qUUtlZw).

Please ping me at chat, if you have any other interesting designs that we can add to the collection.

Comment: @Raphink Code uploaded, still a bit rough. Will periodically update over the next 2-3 days.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Will you provide a CTAN version?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I will but not immediately, I want to add a few things first (such as re-definitions of sections as well) and test extensively. I will upload to ctan possibly in about a month. (I will also upload to github when I am back home after the 17th).

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: This package will be linked very often ;-) - Nice one.

Comment: @user12609 Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank Yiannis by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.

Comment: This definitely deserves the bounty :-) I'll be very happy to see this package on CTAN!

Comment: @Raphink Thanks for the encouragement. Will upload to `ctan` as soon as I feel fairly confident bugs have been ironed out.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides:I can't download the different chapter designs. When I click the link `here`, the file is empty.

Comment: @PigCry Please try the links right at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Do you know if your styles are compatible with `memoir` ?   (Great work btw.)

Comment: @André Thanks! I haven't tested them yet, but I intend to make the package compatible with all classes. Check here in a few days.

Comment: Yiannis, this is more than impressive. I *love* the pgfkeys-based interface and can't wait to see the sectioning support as well :-) Hope this will also work with KOMA.

Comment: Has this made it to CTAN? I'm looking forward to using it!

Comment: Yannis, I can't find the package on CTAN and the links for the sources and PDF documentation are all invalid right now.

Comment: The link given to BOTH the package `chaptersx` and documentation is dead: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B75n0wtctw00YVJGRmJ4d2FUajZyVFBPTTVPNGU0Zw

Comment: @PauloNey Thanks will check it out and reload on github in the evening or early tomorrow. I deleted a lot of my docs and probably wiped it out.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides How can I get this code?

Comment: @ADP I have extended it quite a bit since I first wrote the above, it is still not production ready but you can have a peek at https://github.com/yannisl/phd/blob/master/phd.dtx

Comment: Hello, great examples!  If I ever start writing another textbook for students (I just finished one...), I wish I use these styles.  Are you going to make them into package?

Comment: @YannisLazarides Is there any chance to get these onto CTAN so that we can include it in TeX Live. You might open a git project so that others can contribute or help fix things. I generally have the impression that opening these kind of things helps development. And inclusion in TeX Live would help, too, I guess. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Your googleCode links expired, can you edit the github links in there?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides has there new regarding a publication on CTAN?

Comment: To anyone who follows, the earlier links are still dead, although @yiannis-lazarides 's link to his github repo is still active.

Comment: Where do I put \def\chaptername {BAB}?

Answer (score 58):

You could use [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) together with TikZ. Here's an example which you could modify in color and shape:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
Text
\chapter{Main}
\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy chapter heading example]

Source: [TeXblog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/).

Comment: This is a good example indeed, but I'm more searching for a list of packages that provide built-in styles.

Comment: I have had similar thoughts, but as one of the gurus here once told me, there can never be two persons with the same identical liking and thus what you are looking for may be unique to your demands. I have found that it is always a good idea to start with what you really want and then move on from there.

Comment: Just for the sake of being as exhaustive as possible since this thread sure is among top search results:
Some more examples can be found in my blog, see http://web.slzm.de/blog/latex/schone-kapiteltitelseiten-in-latex/

Comment: how can i change the counter to start from right to left for example :   Chapter 1. thanks

Comment: @Johannes, your blog link from this post is now inactive.

Answer (score -10):

How about more simple solution which evades the usage complicated tikz codes?
Well, it is no TeXer masterclass, however if you want save your time, try this workaround:

1. Draw your fancy page in Microsoft Word for example, and save file as PDF, JPG or PNG.
2. Insert it as picture in your TeX-doc. For a4paper, the code will be...

\cleardoublepage
    \pagestyle{empty}

```
{\centering\includegraphics[width=210mm,height=297mm,trim=+5mm 0 0 +5mm]{test.pdf}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part 1 TestPart}

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
```

[image]

As you see, I did't use the \part{...} directly. As defafault, the 'part' counter has not got influence on section and lower levels in article class, so when you add this part to TOC, do not forget to assign the number maually.

Comment: And then you change a section's title or number, and you need to redraw your entire picture `:)`. I am not saying this is a bad solution, just that it should only apply to parts, preferably where there is no description of the internal subdivisions.

Comment: I agree what you say is not convenient. To minimize time lost, 1) save your source files, and if necessary just edit the part or chapter number. 2) make this fancy titles typesetting process already complete and you need just to put in order your publication.

Comment: Down-voting because the answer requires manual maintenance, as @ienissei noted.

Comment: not many people here would use [word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218567/latex-vs-word-improvements-of-latex-over-the-years) if they can avoid it

Comment: As you said. Word was just for example, but you can use any other soft for the flying title creating, as Photoshop or similar free soft.

Comment: why would you use any other software at a TeX SE?

Comment: If you are about TeX development, I agree that we should to find and create the new solutions without external software. However, if to talk about TeX usage where time is important, currently TeX is not enough comfortable for text and graphics interaction. Personally I use solve this problem by usage external software, but don't urge anyone to do same thing, just suggest this solution as alternative.