# Fancy templates for chapter styles, headings, colours and spacing

Tags: sectioning, chapters, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fancy chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings)

I am new to latex but decided to write my thesis with it. However, I think the standard layout of latex is not super fancy meaning the chapter headings etc. As latex became incredible big nowadays I thought there must be loads of templates one can use which change the style of headings, spacing, colours etc.

However, when I started googling for "latex templates" or "latex chapter styles" and other combinations I hardly did not find a lot of templates at all and the one I found aren't very fancy :D

The 3 I found that look most promising to me are:

www.latextemplates.com

[PDF with many examples](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=latex%20chapter%20templates%20filetype:pdf&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf&ei=YVC7UOj_FcbEsgaw4oHIDQ&usg=AFQjCNG0ovosXiuGy5VGdtUz8Rqg_Px_8g&cad=rja)

[The fncychap package](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=fncychap%20latex&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf&ei=kVG7UIKaOtDSsgatuIDwBw&usg=AFQjCNGVYtsetWsBi2LBG1KrEFeHHPSHQA)

Nevertheless, I was wondering if anybody of you knows some more templates I could have a look at or other webpages which provide such templates?

Cheers

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: thanks! I will have a look at that other question first and see if it is of any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at these options.

```
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

Recall, you will also want to use custom pages like A-1, A-2, B-1, B-2 for anything in an appendix chapter A, and B....   You will also need commands for adding the custom chapter to the table of contents.  Thus, at the beginning of a thesis appendix chapter, use the commands:

```
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\chapter*{Appendix A - Symbols and Notation\markboth{Appendix - Symbols and Notation}{}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}{Appendix - Symbols and Notation}}

{Greek Symbols}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{.5in} \= \\ $\alpha$ \> Alpha \\
                     $\beta$ \> Beta \\
\end{tabbing}
```