# Bold Chapter Name

Tags: titles, chapters, bold

I can make the chapter name bold by using `\textbf{...}` in the text file like:

```
\chapter{\textbf{Scholastic Forest Management Planning and Forest Zoning}}
```

But I want to make the text "Chapter 1" bold  as well.

[image]

In order to achieve the above, here is the class that I used/created

```
% Chapter title formatting
\newcommand*{\chaptertitleformatone}{ % main-matter and appendices
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
          {\normalfont\LARGE\normalfont}
         % {\titleline{\leaders\hrule height 1pt\hfill}
              {\titleline{}
        \vspace{5pt}
        \titleline{}
        \vspace{1pt}
        \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \thechapter}
          {1pc}
          {\titleline{}
        \vspace{0.5pc}
        \LARGE}
```

Comment: Using `\textbf` inside  `\chapter` command is _not_ something encouraged. Strictly speaking, this should be avoided at any cost. Please take a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings), and see if you like any from the links/examples found in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `\bfseries` in the second argument for `\titleformat`; then this will apply to both the "Chapter No" string and to the title; a similar remark applies to `\LARGE`; since you want to use it for all the parts of the title, move it to the second argument.

Also, use `\chaptertitlename` instead of just `\chaptername`; the latter will always produce "Chapter" (or its idiomatic localization), whereas the former will correctly produce "Chapter" or "Appendix" if `\appendix` has been used.

Here's a version of your code (modulo `\titleline{}` which really isn't doing its job in its present form):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{5pt}\titleline{}\vspace{1pt}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{0.5pc}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since, apparently, you are not really interested in having rules in your titles, as the image suggests, your code can be reduced to:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
  {1.5pc}
  {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweak this as you wish.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont}{\Large\scshape\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\LARGE\bfseries #1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{65pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
Text
\chapter{Main}
\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the use of `explicit` here? There's really no need for it to achieve such a simple formatting as the one requested here.