# Where I can get the chapterx package?

Tags: formatting, packages, chapters

I was viewing a good page where Yiannis Lazarides show how to use chapterx and put it on google drive but right now it does´t exist, some one have it o know how to get it?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is the file that I was looking for.
So only I have to discover how to use because it looks so big

Answer (score 4):

You're most likely referring to [Fancy chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50848/5764) (which has the broken link to [`chapterx`](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B75n0wtctw00YVJGRmJ4d2FUajZyVFBPTTVPNGU0Zw). According to [Yiannis' comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings/50848#comment266933_50848), the source has been updated and [now lives on GitHub](https://github.com/yannisl/phd/blob/master/phd.dtx). It's not known as `chapterx` anymore, but `phd`.