# How to customize the chapter with an imported image

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to customize the chapter beginning with a particular image.  How could I do it?
Something like this (the part remarked with a black frame)
[image]

Also, how could start the first paragraph of the chapter with the very first character bigger (occupying two lines) than the others and with a different color from the rest of the text?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For your subsidiary question (first letter of the first paragraph occupying two lines – or more), see the `lettrine`  package. Note the typographical tradition uses small caps for the rest of the word.

Comment: A lot depends on the document class used.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings

Comment: Thanks, Bernard, for the lettrine package information.  It worked as I wanted!!!!

Comment: Crosspost  http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=29972