# How to produce this title page?

Tags: titles, tufte

Please, I would like to create this title page with the image, the page number in the center but without the footer rule

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,nobib,symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\graphicspath{{Images/}} 
%%%%%%%%  
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    {\Huge \bfseries Differential Equations \\[4cm]}
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{image.jpg} \\[2cm]
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

below is the picture
[image]

Comment: Is it a title page, or a chapter heading?

Comment: It looks like a title page so I think chapter heading. Sorry I'm new with latex.

Comment: Hmmm... the confusion is that you posted a screenshot of a chapter heading, and then a code for a title page (they are quite different things: you have several chapter headings in a book, but just one titlepage...)

Comment: I'm very sorry.

Comment: You should take a look at the `titlesec` package.

Comment: @Gallagher what is the name of that textbook ?

Comment: I don't know the name of this textbook so I found these notes on the web (see http://faculty.bard.edu/belk/math213/Notes1.pdf). In fact I would like to produce the same document by latex. Any help for that?

Comment: There are examploe of fancy chapter heading in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings

Comment: Sorry but I do not know how to achieve this chapter heading.