# A specific fancy chapter heading

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

So, basically I'm working on my memoir. TeX and LaTeX are rather new for me. I really looked everywhere to be able to design the same chapter heading as Walter Appel does in his brilliant book called "Mathematics For Physics and physicists !".

This is how it looks:

[image: Chapter Headings From Walter Appel]

I tried using the titlesec package like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}
  {\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}\hbox{\chaptertitlename}\end{adjustbox}\ \color{gray}\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

But I don't know how I can make it look more like Walter Appel does.

I would really appreciate your help. Also, I apologize in advance for my bad English (I'm French) and for the code I provided which is rather not that advanced.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings.  Personally, I avoid titlesec.  I don't need it, and it is much more complicated than the standard \chapter definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge\filcenter}
{\sffamily\rotatebox{90}{\normalsize\chaptertitlename}\,\scalebox{2.24}{\color{Gainsboro}\thechapter}}
  {20pt} {}

  \begin{document}

    \chapter{Some Fancy Chapter}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: psk, stealing the tick with simple versions... :) Have a vote.

Comment: Though I'd use `\Huge` for the chapter number and adapt the scaling factor, because the `\Huge` font might be more suitable for that size (depending on font choice etc.).

Comment: You're right – the code is easier to understand for beginners. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: +1: Even a tikz-free solution :).

Comment: You don't need a sledgehammer to crack a nut :o)

Answer (score 4):

Without using `titlesec` but with manually redefining the internal `\@makechapterhead`. This comes pretty close, the fonts differ and maybe the sizes aren't perfect.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}

\colorlet{chapnum}{black!40}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]
  {%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    \begingroup
      \centering
      \normalfont
      \bfseries
      \rotatebox{90}{\Large\sffamily\chaptername}
      \begingroup
        \scalebox{3.5}{\Huge\color{chapnum}\thechapter}\par\vskip10\p@
      \endgroup
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \Huge
      #1\par
      \nobreak\vskip40\p@
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Convergence et limites}
\blindduck

\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Big thanks!!! That's it. No problem for the font, I didn't wanted to change it anyway.