# Covers for individual chapters

Tags: graphics, chapters, titles, bookcover

I am currently preparing my Latex template for my thesis. For this I am using the Vel template as basis.
However, I would like to edit the chapter covers in a way depicted below. Is there any common packages etc. that I could use for that?

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The following is the template link: https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Comment: Not really.  Tikz could do the full page images.  Just add them to \chapter or \@makechapterhead.  The titlesec package might be able to handle it too.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings for ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!