# How can I avoid that the logos, that are repeated on every page, get overwritten?

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I would like to have a template where our institute logo, website and sponsor logo are repeated on each page in the header without the text overlapping the logo.
So far I have managed to get the logos repeated on each page, but unfortunately have not found a way to avoid the overlap.

I have already spent a few hours on this and would be very grateful if someone could help me!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper ,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-fancyhdr}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lhead{title}
\rhead{\thepage~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}

\IfPackageAtLeastTF{fancyhdr}{2019/03/21}{

\DeclarePageStyleAlias{@fancy}{f@nch@fancycore}
}{

\DeclarePageStyleAlias{f@nch@fancycore}{@fancy}
}
\DeclareNewLayer[{

  background,topmargin,contents={\hfill

    \begin{floatingfigure}[r]{5.cm}\includegraphics[width=4.cm]{example-image-a}

\\\textcolor{white}{aaa}\footnotesize{www.examplesite.com}

    \\\textcolor{white}{aaaaii}\includegraphics[width=2.7cm]{example-image-b}

\end{floatingfigure}}}]{Logo.PNG}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{@fancy}{Logo.PNG}

\usepackage{blindtext,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument




\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

[image: Screenshot_Output]

Comment: This would require a corner to be cut out of the text upper right corner on every page, even in running text (flowing from one paqe to the next). This is extremely difficult in (La)TeX, if at all possible. I would suggest to change the design to keep the logos completely in the header (horizontally, above the text).

Comment: You can achieve this effect using flowfram, but you will have to manually break paragraphs when the column width chages.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574141/tikz-absolute-image-position-and-text-wrapping