# Is there a website with cool chapter style fors scrbook?

Tags: scrbook

Is there a website with cool chapter styles fors scrbook?
Like a gallery, where you see different variants and can copy the code for it?

Comment: something like http://texblog.org/2012/07/03/fancy-latex-chapter-styles/

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjVq4zzjvLyAhUJgP0HHeJfBmgQFnoECA0QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebookation.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2010%2F03%2Fmemoirchapstyles.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0lRdpe1PpYVaSXbPJP0BHA