Chapter layout latex
I'm writing my PhD thesis in LaTeX (using OverLeaf), and I decided to customize the layout of my chapters. My idea is to include a sidebar on every page of a chapter that displays the chapter number.
This works well for the table of contents —as shown in the first image 
— but not for the actual chapters, as you can see in the second image.
 I can't figure out why.
Additionally, the bibliography is treated as a chapter and assigned a chapter number (incorrectly, as it takes the number of the previous chapter) —shown in the third image.

Here is the code I used.
    % auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift  blue!30 \or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\or yellow!30 \or orange!30 \or purple!30 \else black!70 \fi}

% The box for chapter number
\newlength{\chaptNumWd}
\newlength{\sepBlock}
\setlength{\sepBlock}{2em}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

% CHAPTER NUMBER/TITLE LAYOUT
\newcommand\chapterFormat[1]{%
\sbox{\mybox}{%
\ifnum\thechapter>0
\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt]%
\node[%
        fill = \BoxColor,
        minimum width = 4cm,
        minimum height = 4cm,
        inner xsep=1.2em,
        font = \color{white}\fontsize{120}{120}\selectfont %
        ] (block) {\thechapter};
\node[%
        rotate = 90,
        inner xsep=0pt,
        anchor =  center,
        font = \color{black}\LARGE\normalfont
        ] at ([xshift=-15pt] block.west) {\textls[140]{\textsc{Chapter}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\fi
}%
\settowidth{\chaptNumWd}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chaptNumWd-\sepBlock}{\raggedright\LARGE#1}\hfill\usebox{\mybox}%,
\stepcounter{chapshift}
}  

\usepackage{titlesec} % formatting of the chapter title (number+text)
\titleformat{\chapter}% sectioning type to customize
    [block]% shape, here number and title text on a block
    {\normalfont\bfseries\color{\BoxColor}}% format
    {}% formatting code of the section (here chapter) number.
    {0pt}% in "block" shape, the left margin    
    {\chapterFormat}% code before the title text (takes the title of the chapter as the argument)
    [\vspace{1em}{\titlerule[2.5pt]}\vspace{3pt}\titlerule\vspace{4pt}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}% Place the chapter block almost at the top of the page
    {0pt}% space added at left
    {20pt}% vertical space added before
    {20pt}% vertical space added after (space between chapter title and section title, for example)


% SIDE BAR LAYOUT
\newcommand\ChapterBox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip 40\p@}
  {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
\makeatother



\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}
    {
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\slshape\leftmark}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
        \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark\ChapterBox} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
        \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark\ChapterBox} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
    }

\pagestyle{MyStyle} %% added




% Define the color for the ToC
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, % Makes the links colored instead of having a box
    linkcolor=\BoxColor, % Color of the ToC links
    urlcolor=\BoxColor,  % Color of URL links
    citecolor=\BoxColor   % Color of citations (optional)
}

How can I solve these issues?

Welcome! Your code is not compilable. Please give a full example including \documentclass, \begin{document}, \end{document} and the necessary packages.

There are many example of customized chapter headings here.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings for inspiration.  Note that older examples did not have access to \AddToHook{shipout/background}.
